# Fibonacci Search python:

Tags: python, search, fibonacci

I'm following these instructions to create a basic fibonacci search program:

Let `F` be the list of fibonacci (`ListFibonacci`) numbers up to the length `n` of our sorted list (`ListElements`). (If `n` is not a fibonacci number, then `F` contains elements up to the next fibonacci element greater than `n`). Let `X` be the number whose position we need find in our sorted list `ListElements`.

To test if `X` is in `ListElements`, follow these steps:

1) Let `k = F[p-1]` where `p = len(F)` (i.e., the last element of `F`)

2) If `k = 0`, stop. There is no match; `X` is not in the list `ListElements`.

3) Compare `X` against element in `ListElements` at index `F[p−2]`.

4) If `X` matches, stop.

5) If `X` is less than the entry in `ListElements` at index `F[p−2]`, the element `X` must be in the lower section from `1` to `F[p-2]` in `ListElements`. Set `p = p − 1`, `k = F[p-1]` and return to step 2.

6) If the item is greater than entry `F[p-2]`, the element `X` must be in the upper section from `F[p-2]` to `n` in `ListElements`. ***Update the search start address of `ListElements` to `F[p-2]`.*** Set `p = p − 2`, `k = F[p-1]` and return to step 2.

The bold part is where I believe I'm having the most issues, but in general my understanding of 6) is pretty low anyway. To clarify understanding the instruction and writing the program are part of an assignment.

Here's my program at the moment:

```
F = [0,1,1,2,3,5,8]
ListElements = sorted([83,24,65,123,175,57,123,243])
X = 243

p = len(F)
k = F[p-1]

if(k == 0):
    print("K = 0")
else:
    while(True):
        print("test1")
        if(X == ListElements[F[p-2]]):
            print(str(X) + " " + str(p) + " " + str(k))
            break
        elif(X < ListElements[F[p-2]]):
            print("test2")
            p -= 1
            k = F[p-1]
        elif(X > ListElements[F[p-2]]):
            print("test3")
            p -= 2
            k = F[p-1]
```

Below are some outputs:

```
Input: X = 123,
Output: test1
        123 7 8

Input: X = 243,
Output: test1
        File "C:\SNIP", line 20, in <module>
        if(X == ListElements[F[p-2]]):
        IndexError: list index out of range
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        test3
        test1
        test3
        test1
        test3
        test1

Input: 24,
Output: test1
        test2
        test1
        test2
        test1
        test2
        test1
        test2
        test1
        test2
        test1
        24 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your professor or whoever set the assignment is having a laugh, this algorithm is not even close to a base algorithm for a Fibonacci sequence. For starters your point 3

> 3) Compare X against element in ListElements at index F[p−2].

Asks you to use one of the numbers IN the list of fibonacci numbers as an index, it should be

> 3) Compare X against element in ListElements at index p−2.

However this would require both lists to be the same length an there is no prerequisite for this as far as you have shown.

A real algorithm for fibonacci searching can be found on the wikipedia page here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_search_technique

Comment: I'll try and replicate it, haha. And maybe he is! I think he said he copied it of somewhere else, guess it was wrong.